# Modify data in ng-click angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to edit data when I am calling ng-click. Below is the code:

```
<tr class="read" ng-repeat="data in records>
  <td>
   {{data.requestId}}
 </td>
 <td>
   {{data.status}}
 </td>
   <a height="20" class="pointer" 
   ng-click="download(data.downloadPath)" target="_self"></a>
 </td>
```

e.g. - If the value of data.downloadPath is **/opt/dummy/file.txt**, I need to remove the first forward slash and give the path as:  **opt/dummy/file.txt**

Is it possible to edit here in angularjs or do I need to edit the controller code:

```
someSrv.someFunction()
        .success(function(response){

          $scope.records = response.data;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Angular expression is still regular JavaScript, so I guess you can go for

```
ng-click="download(data.downloadPath.slice(1))"
```

Or if the first `/` is optional and not always there, with a regular expression:

```
ng-click="download(data.downloadPath.replace(/^\//, ''))"
```

Comment: *"An Angular expression is still regular JavaScript"*. No it's not. Also because of that the regexp example won't work and throw error.

Comment: The first option does what I need. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing would be to use `substr` method

```
<a  ng-click="download(data.downloadPath.substr(1))" target="_self"></a>
```

This would remove `"/"` altogether. `/dir/index.php` would become `dir/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ng-if` directive to check if the value is equal to `/opt/dummy/file.txt`.

```
<tr class="read" ng-repeat="data in records>
  <td>
   {{data.requestId}}
 </td>
 <td>
   {{data.status}}
 </td>
   <div ng-if="data.downloadPath == '/opt/dummy/file.txt'">
     <a height="20" class="pointer" 
     ng-click="download(data.downloadPath.slice(1))" target="_self"></a>
   </div>
   <div ng-if="data.downloadPath != '/opt/dummy/file.txt'">
     <a height="20" class="pointer" 
     ng-click="download(data.downloadPath)" target="_self"></a>
   </div>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.download = function(dataPath){
    var string = "dataPath";
    if (string.charAt(0) == "/") string = string.substr(1);
    if (string.charAt(string.length - 1) == "/") string = string.substr(0,string.length - 1);
    $scope.path = string;

}
```